# Saving custom fields in devise User model in Rails 4.1.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I just followed [this](http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2011/03/03/rails-%E2%80%93-add-custom-fields-to-devise-user-model/) guide to add the columns 'firstname' and 'secondname' to the Devise User Model with the following commands.

```
rails generate migration add_firstname_to_user firstname:string
rails generate migration add_secondname_to_user secondname:string
```

and I aplied the changes with:

```
rake db:migrate
```

It worked right, because I can see those fields through the console with User.all, however the problem I have now is that I don't see the attr_accessible field in app/model/user.rb.

So I just added the following lines:

```
<div><%= f.label :first_name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :firstname, autofocus: true %></div>

<div><%= f.label :second_name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :secondname, autofocus: true %></div>
```

in new.html.erb in app/views/devise/registrations, but it isn't working, because I noticed that the firstname and secondname attributes are nil on the users I registered.

What can I do?, I guess is something about the attr_accessible step, but I couldn't find it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your `controller`? You have to add those `attributes` to the list of `permitted params`.

Answer (score 1):

For custom fields 'first name' and 'second name', you can make them accessible by adding following code in your application controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
     devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :firstname, :secondname) }
     devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :firstname, :secondname) }
     devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, :firstname, :secondname) }
  end
end
```

You can add more custom fields and permitting them here, Change the code correspondingly as per your needs.